# C++ inheritance, how solve this?

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can I solve this? I want to execute proper method something. Is there any way to solve this?
I want to execute method something in one loop.

```
class Base
{
public:
    void something() {}
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    void something() {}
};

class SecondChild : public Base
{
public:
    void something() {}
};

std::vector<Base*> vbase;

Child * tmp = new Child();

vbase.push_back((Base*) tmp);

SecondChild * tmp2 = new SecondChild();

vbase.push_back((Base*) tmp);

for (std::vector<Base*>::iterator it = vbase.begin(); it != vbase.end(); it++)
{
    //here's problem, I want to execute proper method "something", but only I can do is execute Base::something;
    (*it)->something();
}
```

I don't know how to cast type, when I got many children of base class.

Comment: You need virtual functions. And use smart pointers while you're at it.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328022/confused-with-c-inheritance?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of things.

One, you don't need to cast stuff to `(Base*)`. Implicit conversions will do that for you already. Second, if you define your functions as `virtual` it will call the proper function for you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the method as `virtual` in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to make `something()` a `virtual` function.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void something() {}
};
...
[in a function]
Base *p = new Child;
p->something(); //calls Child's something
```